# Accuracy of quantum mechanical algorithms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, algorithms

Is it possible for a quantum mechanical algorithm to ensure when the wave function collapses that the right answer will be obtained 100% of the time?
For this, I am excluding processes such as decoherence which can cause this number to become lower. I am talking about purely the algorithms which are used to obtain an answer to a problem. Can such algorithms theoretically exist that provide the correct answer 100% of the time?

Comment: Are you asking about [quantum error corrections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction)? Please give a bit more context what you understand under a "quantum mechanical algorithm".

Comment: Thanks, have added edits now, and no I am not referring to quantum error correction algorithms

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. For example, [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) seems to always terminate when it has found the correct output, and so should *all* algorithms - else, they aren't *algorithms* if they don't terminate with identical outputs for the same inputs!

Comment: I know that! For your specific case on Shor's algorithm, there is a probability that you will have to restart the algorithm from scratch, that in my opinion is not 100% accurate. 100% accurate would be that it would provide the correct result, regardless of the random seed inputted to the algorithm.